# Does installing boost can mess up my programs?

Tags: c++, boost

I have downloaded boost and it is a massive directory of thousands of files. I have have gcc 3.4.5 - an old version compared to what's out now but it runs with my old programs that I keep working with. I was thinking of giving my programs a bit more edge by having boost installed, especially the shared_ptr thingy seems a fine addition. My question is installing boost could lead to my programs not running anymore or are the boost library files an completely independent object?

Comment: I had the same problem too. I tried to download boost for AMD-64 bit machine but the installation failed. I could not port it to 64 bit machine. So I forgot about it.

Comment: That version isn't old, it's *ancient*. You should really update your compiler.

Comment: Pay no attention to `boost::shared_ptr` and go straight to `std::shared_ptr`. As you will do source rewrites anyway, why opt for the older non-standard alternative? And yeah 3.x is ancient at this point.

Comment: i think boost doesnt even not support that old compiler... depends of boost version ofc... but ignoring that boost is independant of your comiler, it doesnt overwrite anything or stuff like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question right, and disregarding compiler version issues, the answer is yes. Boost libraries that are not header-only are typically built out-of-the-box as a set of dynamic libraries (i.e. a set of .dll, .so or .dylib files depending on platform).

Building and installing a newer version of boost can therefore mess up your existing installed programs in the following situation:

- if you already have programs installed on your system, that link against an existing version of some non-header boost library at runtime
- and if the newer version has had interface changes or subtle implementation changes

then your existing program may be messed up (unable to run or subtle bugs, depending on more precise situation details) by the newer boost library you installed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand your question. Are you talking about distributing binaries? You can link boost statically and dynamically. If you link them statically, the size of your binary gets a little bigger, but you are not dependend on boost system libraries. That is the typical way to do it with Windows. With Linux-based systems, boost is typically linked dynamically against the system libraries and in general it is very reliable. However some modules like filesystem or program_options have a record of incompatible API changes.

Or are you talking about compatibility with your ancient compiler version? Boost is not 100% compatible with such an old GCC, but the core functionality should work.